# Error in macking a copy of database with mysqldump in java

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, runtime

My java code is:

```
String[] command = new String[]{db.getMysqlpath()+"\\mysqldump","--opt","-uroot" ,"-p123","store", " | ","mysql","-uroot","-p123","-c","cs"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(command));
processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);

Process process = processBuilder.start();
process.waitFor()
```

Get this error in output
Mysqldump:couldnot find table : " | "
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: I think the error message is self explanatory. Have you tried executing the same command in a terminal before writing the Java code? If yes, what's the output?

Comment: Yes my command is true and copy information to new database 'cs'